# `reset` terminal but preserving the scrollback buffer

Tags: terminal, scrolling

I use the `reset` command when my terminal is in a wrong state and regular shell interaction doesn't work as it should. This usually happens when a program configured the terminal in some way and then exited abnormally. Usually because I was running over an SSH session that disconnected.

But often I have something in my scrollback buffer that I would like to preserve. `reset` also clears the scrollback buffer. Is there any way to do what the `reset` command does without clearing the scrollback buffer?

Comment: Try the "soft terminal reset" escape sequence: `printf '\e[!p'`

Comment: @egmont What is that supposed to do? I tried it and it does stop the terminal from capturing mouse button presses/scrolls, but does not leave the alternate screen.

Comment: I don't know off the top of my head what attributes it resets exactly. It resets plenty, but not all. (The exact behavior might even vary across terminal emulators.) You may write an alias / shell fuction / script which in addition resets the ones you wish (e.g. switch back to normal screen).